# Why after splitting the state into two parts dont work some part app?

Tags: reactjs

I have one big state in component

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    props1: [],
    props2: someValue,
    props3: someValue,
    props4: someValue,
    props5: someValue,
    props6: someValue,
    props7: someValue,
    props8: someValue,
});
```

And eight methods like this:

```
const methodsName = () => {         
     setValue({
        props1: someNewValue,
    });
   };
```

But tomorrow I will need to remake my react application in Redux. There I will have two reducers. Each reducer has its own state. Props 1-4 in first reducer, props 5-8 in second reducer. So now I decided to split my state into two states for convenience and and a better vision.

And I try to make it:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    props1: [],
    props2: someValue,
    props3: someValue,
    props4: someValue
});

const [valueB, setValueB] = useState({
    props5: someValue,
    props6: someValue,
    props7: someValue,
    props8: someValue,
});

// for props 1-4
const methodsNameOne = () => {         
     setValue({
        props1: someNewValue,
    });
   };

/......

// for props 5-8
const methodsNameFive = () => {         
     setValueB({
        props5: someNewValue,
    });
   };

/......
```

#### But all the functionality of the site that implements methods with props 5-8 does not work.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing great, as much you've told. I have created a `React functional component` to demonstrate you and tested it, this state is being updated like butter, see this-

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


const Stackoverflow = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3,
    fourth: 4
  });
  const [valueB, setValueB] = useState({
    sixth: 6,
    seventh: 7,
    eighth: 8,
    ninth: 9
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setValue({...value, first: 10});
  }
  const handleClickB = () => {
    setValueB({...valueB, sixth: 60});
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{value.first}</p> {/* before -1, after -10 */}
      <p>{valueB.sixth}</p> {/* before -6, after -60 */}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <button onClick={handleClickB}>ClickB</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Stackoverflow;
```

Comment: I edit question. Maybe it related with setValue in fetch?

Comment: Try to put, console.log for the fetched `data.data` that you have fetched using `fetch` API for both cases that are working and that are not working.

Comment: I get the data normally. Data I diplay in props in state 1. Also in state 1 I have props for filtering this data. In state 2  I have props for adding,edit, and delete category in server.

Comment: I didn't get 'normally' what do you mean by "I get the data normally"? please elaborate.

Comment: I find problem. In children components I instead `valueB` write `value`